# Is there a way to use push.default = current AND set it up to track that remote branch automatically?

Tags: git

I have the following in `.gitconfig`:

```
[push]
  default = current
```

This is handy because if I create a new branch locally and push, it will automatically create a remote branch with the same name if it doesn't already exist. However, Git doesn't set up tracking for it, which means if I want to pull remote changes back to my local branch, I first have to run

```sh
git branch -u origin/<local-branch> <local-branch>
```

E.g.

```sh
git checkout -b did_not_exist_on_remote
git commit -m "empty commit" --allow-empty
git push

# I want to skip this step and go straight to pulling
git branch -u origin/did_not_exist_on_remote did_not_exist_on_remote
git pull
```

Is there a way to either ask Git to set up tracking at time of push (with `branch.default = current`, without using `-u`) or for Git to detect that there is a branch in one of the remotes with the same name at time of pull and set up tracking then?

(I suspect the latter might be hard because multiple remotes might have the same branch name, and there's no way to indicate a "default" remote?)

Comment: The short answer is "no, use `-u`" (consider `git push -u` here). However, there *is* now a "preferred remote" configuration knob, so that the checkout/switch DWIM/guess code can pick the remote out of a collection of N remotes, when you `git checkout foo` and there are N possible `remoteN/foo` sources. I don't remember offhand which Git version first gained this preferred-remote knob.

Comment: FWIW: I personally find that the more flexible setting is `git config --global push.default upstream`, and to "automatically create a remote branch with the same name", I just run `git push -u origin HEAD`.

Comment: Try `git config --local branch.autoSetupRebase true`